# What is the meaning of "Stack up against"?

Tags: idioms

Does `Stack up against` mean comparatively to level up in performance?

> Performance wise, junior students need to **stack up against** the seniors to set a high reputation.

Is it a correct construction?

Comment: @BobRodes, In that case is the above sentence correct?

Comment: Perhaps a good synonymous term is "compare well with."  The idiom means to be roughly equivalent to something in terms of capability or quality.  As such, "perform about as well as the seniors" is another way of expressing it here.  FYI, "stack up with" and "stack up to" are also fairly common.  Note that these two also often have different meanings, such as "you can stack up to 12 chips in one pile and no more."

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the idiom can be used in that way. Here are some examples:

> We wondered how London restaurants stacked up against Atlanta's.
>
> Their gift doesn't stack up against mine
>
> The new ​model of this ​car just doesn't ​stack up against ​previous ​models

The idiom refers to stacking up your poker chips against somebody else's: either your stack is as high as theirs, or it isn't. It's not something that you can "need to" or "try to".

A better way of expressing what you want to say would be:

> Junior students need to perform as well as the seniors to get a good reputation

Comment: In my opinion to your answer, I suppose it should be "as good as"  in the place of "as well as".

Comment: @Gt_R, **perform** is a verb: you have to qualify it with an adverb **well**, not an adjective **good**. http://gtotd.blogspot.com.eg/2011/09/use-adverbs-instead-of-incorrect.html

Comment: Got it. very helpful for further learning.    So, is 'stacking against' for comparison in numbers?

Comment: @Gt_R, It could be used for numbers but that's relatively rare. If you look at the three examples I quoted, they are all subejctive comparisons, not numerical ones.

Comment: @JavaLatteSo, when you say "We wondered how London restaurants stacked up against Atlanta's"   what does it mean?  Does it mean, they are at same standards?!

Comment: Exactly, it's about quality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38485/discussion-between-gt-r-and-javalatte).

Answer (score 0):

If you took the original sentence,

> Performance wise, junior students need to **stack up against** the seniors to set a high reputation.

and replaced "stack up aganist" with this,

> Performance wise, junior students need to **compare to** the seniors to set a high reputation.

it would have the same meaning. So you could say that "stack up aganist" means "to be comparable to".